# Grouping days into months between 2 dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

Lets say we have:

```
$startDt="10/28/2017";
$endDt="12/2/2017";
```

I want to get array of days grouped into months in between these dates. Output must be like:

```
[
   "October"=>[28, 29, 30, 31],
   "November"=>[1, ..., 30],
   "December"=>[1,2]
]
```

Can't figure out how to achieve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5):

You can use PHP's built-in classes [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) for this; e.g:

```
<?php 

$start = new DateTime('10/28/2017');    
$end = new DateTime('12/2/2017');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 day

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$days = [];  

foreach ($period as $dt) {
  $month = $dt->format('F');
  $day = $dt->format('j');
  $days[$month][] = $day;
} 

print_r($days);
```

[Here is the documentation about date formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Note that `DatePeriod` goes up to but *excludes* the last date if the times are the same (which is the case here, so you probably want to modify the end date to address this - adding a second should do the trick; e.g:

```
$end = new DateTime('12/2/2017');
$end->modify('+1 second');
// or $end->setTime(0, 0, 1); H/T to @ishegg

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
// etc.
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [October] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => 29
            [2] => 30
            [3] => 31
        )

    [November] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
            [9] => 10
            [10] => 11
            [11] => 12
            [12] => 13
            [13] => 14
            [14] => 15
            [15] => 16
            [16] => 17
            [17] => 18
            [18] => 19
            [19] => 20
            [20] => 21
            [21] => 22
            [22] => 23
            [23] => 24
            [24] => 25
            [25] => 26
            [26] => 27
            [27] => 28
            [28] => 29
            [29] => 30
        )

    [December] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It doesn't *exclude* the date, it just uses the current time (because it's not set) in both dates and the last day doesn't get picked up. I think it might be better (in case he, for example, wants to use `$end` afterwards) to modify the time rather than the date, `$start->setTime(0, 0, 0); $end->setTime(0, 0, 1);`

Comment: @ishegg Updated my answer to reflect that. Cheers :)

Comment: `modify()`ing to add 1 second is a much better idea!

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. One more question: How to get date in database format (for ex. 2017-12-02) for each date inside `foreach` loop?

Comment: Also it returns answer in reverse order. Like December, November, October. How to reverse result?

Comment: Hi @Terminus - you'd format a date like the example above like `$dt->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: @Terminus - I'm not sure what you mean in your second question - can you elaborate? PHP associative arrays are ordered and the keys are added sequentially by month so they should be in order, as per the following example: https://3v4l.org/ub7EU